# Formal tools to prove $\vec v = [ \vec x_1 \in \mathbb{R}^{n-m}, \vec x_2 \in \mathbb{R}^m] \rightarrow \vec v \in \mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

I'm stuck on a proof that needs as part of it $\vec v = [ \vec x_1 \in \mathbb{R}^{n-m}, \vec x_2 \in \mathbb{R}^m] \rightarrow \vec v \in \mathbb{R}^n$, but I have no clue what references to linear algebra I need, could anyone point me to the proper formal tools to prove this statement? (or if anyone has search terms or reading suggestions, it would be super helpful) It makes very intuitive sense, since it's just a vector of two vectors, and so it makes sense to combine the dimensions, but I'm not too sure how I could proceed with the proof. Any hints are appreciated!

Comment: This statement is not literally true, at least for most ways of setting up the definitions.  What do you *actually* want to prove?

Comment: @EricWofsey ah... thanks for clearing that up, I'll have to review linear algebra